# ContactKey does not appear in Contact Builder -> All Contacts -> Mobile Push - React Native (IOS)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, marketingcloudapi, react-native, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I followed all the steps in the **react-native-marketingcloudsdk** documentation, including activating the push, but the set contactKey does not appear in the Contact Builder.

SDK log is returning, push is enabled, but no information appears on the platform

Note: The contactkey and other information appear on the platform for Android devices.

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk/blob/master/ios_push.md

Comment: How do you see the information on the platform ? I don't see anywhere about the Contact Key.

Answer (score 0):

hope this react native code helps you.

```
MCReactModule.getContactKey().then(res => {
          if (!res) {
            MCReactModule.setContactKey(AccountNumber);
          }
        });
```